# How to Use below code in apex class PageReference Method

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf

I have a requirement to generate invoices(PDF Files) in my application. So i installed app exchange app "S-Docs" to get it done. But the problem is every time  i need to click on the button to generate the PDF file. So i thought of automating it with out click of button. 
The code present in button was as below

```
        /apex/SDOC__SDCreate1?id={!RecordId}&Object=Claim__c&doclist=Templateid
```

Now i have both recordid and templateid. So whenever i insert a record in Invoice object i am using a trigger to call Page Reference method of a class.
Now i am struck at how to pass the above code in Page Reference  method. Can anyone help me on this.

The code i tried so far is

```
   public PageReference generate(Id cid){
   PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/SDOC__SDCreate1?id='+cid);
   pg.getParameters().put('Object', 'Claim__c');
   pg.getParameters().put('doclist', 'a079000000O8IbL');
   pg.setredirect(true);
   return pg;
  }
```

When i treid to print pg variable  using debug statements what i look is below

```
   pg:System.PageReference[/apex/SDOC_SDCreate1?doclist=a079000000O8IbL&id=a089000000gjZUxAAM&Object=Claim__c]
```

How can i correct the order of passing as i need it?

Comment: What have you tried so far with [PageReference](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm)?

Comment: @BarCotter : please check it now

Comment: Using PageReferences this way won't work within a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect to a page from a trigger, if that is what you want. 
But you can insert the pdf generated from a VF page into an attachment.

This too isn't all that straight forward.

Your trigger would need to call a future method, which in turn makes a callout to a web service that will generate and insert the attachment. ( If you haven't done this before it might seem like a lot of work to accomplish a little thing, but unfortunately that is to overcome the limitation of Salesforce)

Below is some parts of code which I tried in my org some months back. You can make changes to it according to your requirement.

Trigger

```
trigger AfterUpdate on Account (after update) {

List<id> accntIdList = new List<Id>();

for(Account acc: Trigger.new){
    accntIdList.add(acc.id);
}

FutureAttachmentCreator.createAttachment(accntIdList);
}
```

Future Method

```
global class FutureAttachmentCreator{

@Future(callout=true)
public static void createAttachment(list<id> accntIdList){
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setEndpoint('https://'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()+'/services/apexrest/createpdf/');
   req.setMethod('POST');
   req.setBody('{"accountIdList":'+JSON.serialize(accntIdList)+'}');
   req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ sessionId);
   req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   Http http = new Http();
   HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```

}

REST API

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/createpdf/*')
global with sharing class AddPDFtoRecordREST{

  @HttpPost
    global static void doPost(list<String> accountIdList) {
       list<attachment> attachmentList = new list<attachment>();
        for(String accntId: accountIdList){
            //VF page that renders as PDF
            pageReference pdfPage = Page.accntRefPDFPage;
            // passing the parameter to the page
            pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',accntId);
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            Blob body;
            if(!test.isRunningTest()){
                body = pdfPage.getContent();
            }else{
                body=blob.valueOf('test content');
            }
            attachment.Body = body;
            attachment.Name = 'Ref Pdf '+System.now()+'.pdf';
            attachment.IsPrivate = false;
            attachment.ParentId = pdfPage;//This is the record to which the pdf will be attached
            attachmentList.add(attachment);
         }
         //insert the list of attachment
         insert attachmentList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `=` after id. It should be: `?id='+cid);`

**Update:**

```
 PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/SDOC__SDCreate1');
 pg.getParameters().put('id',cid);
```

**Update 2 to enforce order:**

The order really shouldn't matter but if you really need it in that order try this:

```
PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/SDOC__SDCreate1?id='+cid+'&Object=Claim__c&doclist=a079000000O8IbL');
```

Comment: Tried the same but still no luck. Is this the correct way to pass the parameters as i mentioned in code.

Comment: @sunny I added a 2nd suggestion. Try adding the id to the URL just like the other URL parameters.

Comment: No that didnt work either

Comment: @sunny what is your debug saying then?

Comment: Same as previously i have updated in my question.

Comment: Sorry I just re-read part of your question, not sure if it was added later or I just missed it. The trigger isn't going to be able to accomplish this.

Comment: Then how to do this. I am calling the method from trigger. What should be workaround for this.